# BigQuery : rowAccessPolicies.list with a python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api, google-cloud-functions

I want to use a python script to retrieve the policies I have created into BigQuery. The issue is regarding themissing required authentication credential. It is said the script is Expecting OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. But I am not sure where to find it and where to position it in my script. Someone can help me please.

---

My code:

import requests

```
response = requests.get("https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project123/datasets/Dataset123/tables/Test/rowAccessPolicies")

response.json()
```

---

Desired output:

```
{
  "rowAccessPolicies": [
    {
      "rowAccessPolicyReference": {
        "projectId": "project123",
        "datasetId": "Dataset123",
        "tableId": "Test",
        "policyId": "test_2"
      },
      "filterPredicate": "gender = \"M\"",
      "creationTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:35.181602Z",
      "lastModifiedTime": "2021-11-09T09:45:35.181602Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Actual ouptut:

```
  {'error': {'code': 401,
      'message': 'Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.',
      'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED',
      'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo',
        'reason': 'CREDENTIALS_MISSING',
        'domain': 'googleapis.com',
        'metadata': {'method': 'google.cloud.bigquery.v2.RowAccessPolicyService.ListRowAccessPolicies',
     'service': 'bigquery.googleapis.com'}}]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in your message: "Request is missing required authentication credential". You should provide the credentials in your request. You have several ways to do so:

- add the credentials in the headers (depending on the type of authentication you have)
- use Google Api Core (https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html)
- or use the Google Cloud Python lib which has this procedure include (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python)

Comment: I have been able to authentificate and have been able to query CREATE ROW LEVEL SECURITY and SELECT information as well. The issue I have is the fact once I am trying to have access to the list of access policies created through the following request requests.get("https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project123/datasets/Dataset123/tables/Test/rowAccessPolicies"). I have an issue saying the credential are not good. SO the point is the fact on one side I have been able to authenticate myself to run a sql query but one I am trying to use a request, it is not working

Comment: Does the role have enough privileges to run this query?

Comment: I think so since I have been able to run previous query and I have read that other specific privilefes need to be given to the role. Or which privileges do you think need to be given to the role? (thanks for the help)

Comment: Check the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-row-level-security